# FOSUserBundle - how to hold user on homepage after he sent register form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, registration

I render my registration form on homepage using `{% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}`. Everything works fine, but when user send this form, Symfony redirect him to default FOSUserBundle registration page and it's my problem, becouse I want to render this form again (with errors or with success message) on my homepage. I completely don't know how to do it! It is possible?

I had the same problem with login form but I used this code in `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: acme__my_homepage
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                failure_path: acme__my_homepage
```

But I can't find above options for registration...

My files:

**src\MyBundle\Resources\views\homepage.html.twig**

```
<div class="window">
{% render url('fos_user_registration_register') %}
</div>
```

**app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\register.html.twig**

```
<form>
    <input class="myCustomFormInput" name="username" />
    <input class="myCustomFormInput" name="email" />
    <input class="myCustomFormInput" name="password" />
    <input class="myCustomFormInput" name="rpassword" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into Fos controller:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md

There is some exapmle for resetting password, you have to do it similar to registration_success event. Just return RedirectResponse.